# Create a plugin in jquery to style each element separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating my first plugin in jquery. I have went through the basics and now I have started to work on it. My approach is simple. I want to allow users to style each element differently.

E.g

```
     $('#form').style({                         
      inputelement:{
         border:'red',
         color:'#dcdcdc'
      }
  });
```

Goal for this plugin is to allow users to style elements independently

`inputelement` will be the id of the element of my form. I want to apply styles to elements of a form.

I know it can be easily done using css, but I want to experiment with plugins in jquery.

I think this is some advanced concept which I am thinking of, but I need some sort of output like this.

Comment: I am not understanding your question. How are users going to style elements? Why cant you just use `css()` ?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Where is the code for the plugin itself? WHat is the question? WHat is the overall goal for this plugin?

Comment: Seems like you are re-inventing the wheel here.  If you are passing in the styles to plugin, as @AmmarCSE says, why not just use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some of the commentators have mentioned, you are re-inventing the wheel here. You can achieve the same thing by this.

```
$('#form').children('input').css({..})
.children('label').css({..});
```

Comment: Perhaps my question is too broad to mention here. Anyways, thanks.